# What happens if I forget to add taxonomy topics when I submit my paper?

Tags: elsevier, paper-submission

I submitted a paper recently to an elsevier journal. During the submission, I forgot to add the taxonomy topics related to my manuscript. After I completed the submission, I received an email that the manuscript was received successfully. However, it has been 2 days and the manuscript status is still "With Journal". Is this because I forgot to add the taxonomy topics. If yes, what should I do to fix this.

Thanks in advance for your help ...

Answer (score 2):

If this is an issue, it will most likely be flagged by the production staff when the paper is returned from review. But it typically takes a few days to get sorted through the editorial system, so it shouldn't be the lack of taxonomy holding it up.